# Netsuite - linking products?

Tags: salesforce, netsuite

I'm working on an integration between Salesforce and Netsuite.

The company I work for uses 'versions' of products, for example Custom Laptop v1.0, Custom Laptop v2.0.

From what we've seen, Netsuite doesn't really like to group these products at all - they're all just individual products with no relevance to each other.

This makes it difficult when placing orders via Salesforce as the salesperson and customer isn't bothered about what version of the product they're buying, we just want the process to be -

1. Order placed for Custom Laptop in Salesforce
2. Order goes to Netsuite
3. Warehouse team picks product and decides which version to pick, which stock pool it comes from
4. Order is fulfilled

Is there anything in Netsuite that would allow a 'grouping' of products? I looked at product kits but this seems more manufacturing based.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Lot Numbered Inventory Items would work for you here.  With lot numbered items, you have a single item and define multiple 'lots' which can be named anything you'd like.

You would have a single item record in NetSuite (Custom Laptop).  When an order is placed for that item, your warehouse determines which lot to choose from (v1.0, v2.0, v2.1, etc).  The lot number is entered on the Item Fulfillment and the order is shipped.

Answer (score 0):

@mike-robbins' solution would be the way to go if you have fixed inventory of each item. I'm not sure you can receive multiple duplicate lot numbers though.

What I have done in situations similar to this is to create assemblies and turn on assembly versioning. An assembly can have a single component so in your case the minimum components of Assembly 'Laptop' would be

```
Component   Qty Revison 
-----------------------
Laptop v1    1    A
Laptop v2    1    B
```

Version A would have only Laptop v1 and Version B would have Laptop v2. The assembly could also contain any common things where tracking stock or COGS is desired.